# Is there a way to create a nuget package consisting multiple projects including some which dont have reference to any other project?

Tags: azure-devops, dll, nuget, nuget-package, azure-artifacts

I have following dll's among others in a solution:

- Base
- Core
- Basics
- R1
- R2
- Types

I want to put them all in one single nuget package and upload it to Azure DevOps -> Artifacts. Is this possible ?

Comment: Sure, create your own nuspec and runnit.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to create a nuget package consisting multiple projects
> including some which dont have reference to any other project?

The short answer is Yes, We could **use .nuspec to pack up the assemblies**:

1. Download the [nuget.exe](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html).
2. Create a new project.
3. Open a cmd and switch path to nuget.exe
4. Use command line: `nuget spec "PathOfProject\TestDemo.csproj"`
5. Open the `TestDemo.csproj.nuspec` file and modify it and add the assemblies as file; below is my .nuspec file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <package>
     <metadata>
       <id>TestDemo</id>
       <version>1.0.0</version>
       <authors>Tester</authors>
       <owners>Tester</owners>
       <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
       <description>TestDemo</description>
       <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
       <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
       <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
     </metadata>
     <files>
       <file src="ThePathOfTheDll\*.Base.dll" target="lib\net461" />
       <file src="ThePathOfTheDll\*.Core.dll" target="lib\net461" />
       <file src="ThePathOfTheDll\*.Basics.dll" target="lib\net461" />
       <file src="ThePathOfTheDll\*.R1.dll" target="lib\net461" />
       <file src="ThePathOfTheDll\*.R2.dll" target="lib\net461" />
       <file src="ThePathOfTheDll\*.Types.dll" target="lib\net461" />
     </files>
   </package>
   ```
6. Use pack command: `nuget pack TestDemo.csproj.nuspec`

Besides, if your project is donet project, you can edit your csproj file, add an ItemGroup to include the dlls as below: This will pack the other dlls along with your current project dll in the nuget package:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="<path to other dll>">
        <Pack>true</Pack>
        <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: The first way worked for me but the dll from whom i created the nuget package and added the files wasnt in the package when i installed the package to test it. Im gonna try to add it by upgrading the version.